# Exceptions when using MVC routing in an MVC + Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-5

I created an MVC 5 Angular 2 app which works fine when I run it. However, after loading, if I navigate to another page (like About) I get an exception saying: The selector "my-app" did not match any elements. Here is all the relevant code:

Folder structure:

```
| - App
|   | - app.ts
|   | - boot.ts
|   | - main.ts
|
| - Views
|   | - Shared
|       | - _Layout.cshtml
|
| - systemjs.config.js
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="~/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>


    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>


    <script src="~/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="~/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

systemjs.config.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': '../node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: '../App',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './boot';
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

boot.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `    
    <h2>My favorite skill is: {{myskills}}</h2>
    <p>Skill:</p>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let skl of skills">
        {{ skl }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'ASP.NET MVC 5 with Angular 2';
    skills = ['MVC 5', 'Angular 2', 'TypeScript', 'Visual Studio 2015'];
    myskills = this.skills[1];
}
```

Let me know if I missed anything of if more information is required.

**UPDATE**

Here's a screenshot of the error:
[image: Error]

**UPDATE 2**

Here's the index.cshtml code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

_Layout.cshtml is the shared view and index.cshtml is where the angular app lies. Any other MVC view would also have all the code in _Layout.cshtml.

Thanks!

Comment: you are routing through `angular` or `mvc`?

Comment: MVC. I haven't added any angular routing logic. It's a very basic app.

Comment: what is the error you are facing?

Comment: Since you are bootstraping the angular app with AppComponent, it is looking for the app component selector as a starting point which doesn't seem to be used in your Layout view. Normally you do this in the index.html in angular. So basically you need to put <my-app></my-app> as a starting location in order to bootstrap the app but I'm not sure how you would do this exactly with asp.net. In angular-cli you configure the index file but idk how you can tell angular to look at Layout file to find that <my-app></my-app> node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Yeysides! You're explanation helped me figure it out. All I had to do was move the bootstrapping script from _Layout.cshtml to Index.cshtml. So Index.cshtml looks like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
}
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

That fixed the issue.